# Accessing Folder In Group Account C# Outlook

Tags: c#, vba, vb.net, c#-4.0, outlook

I have a group account connected to my outlook. I want to  access a folder in that group. How might I do that?

The group email is mm@abc.com

I can access folders from my regular account using the following code..

```
Dim otkApp As Outlook.Application = New Outlook.Application
Dim ns As Outlook.NameSpace = otkApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Dim otkInboxFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder = ns.GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox)
Thread.Sleep(5000)
```

Comment: Your example code is `VB.NET`, are you looking for a `VB.NET` specific implementation? If so please remove the `C#` tag.

Comment: a c# or vb.net solution is fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Outlook object model provides the [GetSharedDefaultFolder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff869575.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) method of the Namespace class which returns a Folder object that represents the specified default folder for the specified user.

```
Sub ResolveName() 
 Dim myNamespace As Outlook.NameSpace 
 Dim myRecipient As Outlook.Recipient 
 Dim CalendarFolder As Outlook.Folder 
 Set myNamespace = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI") 
 Set myRecipient = myNamespace.CreateRecipient("mm@abc.com") 
 myRecipient.Resolve 
 If myRecipient.Resolved Then 
   Call ShowCalendar(myNamespace, myRecipient) 
 End If 
End Sub 

Sub ShowCalendar(myNamespace, myRecipient) 
 Dim CalendarFolder As Outlook.Folder 
 Set CalendarFolder = _ 
 myNamespace.GetSharedDefaultFolder _ 
 (myRecipient, olFolderCalendar) 
 CalendarFolder.Display 
End Sub
```

Comment: Can you change the code to access a folder called "MyCustomFolder" instead of calender informaiton?

Comment: myRecipent.Resolve() throws the following exception..Operation aborted (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80004004 (E_ABORT))

Comment: Take a look at the [similar](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/6a5846a6-327c-4f8a-9021-cafa5f0bc45f/exception-from-hresult-0x80004004-eabort-when-outlook-not-loaded?forum=vsto) forum thread which describes the issue.